# Decrement value in mysql but not negative

Tags: mysql, decrement

I want to decrement a value when user delete it in php and mysql. I want to check not to go below than 0. If value is 0 then do not **decrement**.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field = field - 1 WHERE id = $number");
```

If field is **0** then do not do anything

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Add another condition to update only if the `field` is greater `0`

```
UPDATE your_table 
SET field = field - 1
WHERE id = $number
AND field > 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel pretty stupid now but I'm happy to have found your answer.

Answer (score 46):

You could prevent the new value to drop below zero by using [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest). If the value drops below zero, zero will always be greater than your calculated value, thus preventing any value below zero to be used.

```
UPDATE  table
SET     field = GREATEST(0, field - 1)
WHERE   id = $number
```

And on a side note: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions any more. They are deprecated and will eventually be removed from PHP. Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead.

Comment: Only if you use [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) as well. You need to replace everything that starts with `mysql_` with another function either from MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: best. this works with increment, not only decrement.

Comment: Nice solution! It works not only decrement, but with any number that is subtracted. On the contrary, accepted answer is OK only for decrement/increment.

Comment: In this case I got error "Error Code: 1690. BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in `table`.`field` - 1" if field is unsigned.

Comment: I had the same error as @frops. The solution is to add a CAST: GREATEST(0, CAST(field AS SIGNED) - 1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer and dear @Matthieu.V : )

Answer (score 12):

The option using GREATEST will not work in newer MySQL versions, and the accepted answer can be unuseful if you want to update multiple fields instead of one. My solution for this problem is using IF:

```
UPDATE  table
SET     field = IF(field > 0, field - 1, 0)
WHERE   id = $number
```

Comment: I don't see anything that says the GREATEST function won't work with newer MySQL versions. As of October 2016, MySQL version 2.7 docs still have it listed, with no mention of deprecation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest

Comment: [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) still available in MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table SET field = case when (field - 1) >0 then (field - 1)
else field end
WHERE id = $number
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 UPDATE `table_name` SET field = field-1 WHERE `id` = '".$id."' AND field > 0
```

Note: field's data-type should be an INTEGER.

Answer (score 1):

if the field is int unsigned, below is the best:

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET field = field - 1
WHERE id = $number
and field > 0

# or
UPDATE  table
SET     field = IF(field > 0, field - 1, 0)
WHERE   id = $number
```

Answer (score -1):

For someone who search an exemple with PDO
Quickly ...

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Set_quantity_product
 */
 class Set_quantity_product {
    
    
  /**
    * Set_quantity_product::update_quant_prod( $id, $number, $to_do );
    *
    * @param  {int} $id        a product id
    * @param  {int} $number    a number to increment or decrement for a value in DB
    * @param  {str} $to_do     'incr/decr'
    * @return {void}           increment or decrement but always return 0 if quant < 0
    */
    public static function update_quant_prod( $id, $number, $to_do ){
    
       $DATA_BASE = new PDO('mysql:host='.$YOUR_HOST.';dbname='.$YOUR_DB_NAME.';charset=utf8', $YOUR_USER_NAME, $YOUR_DB_PASSWORD, array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
    
       // Note:
       // UPDATE  products
       // SET     quant = GREATEST( 0, quant+:ope )
       // WHERE   id = :id
       // increm or decrement but do nothing if quant is > quant in DB
    
       // pass quant number to affect to negative for decrement
       $number = ( $to_do == 'decr' ) ? $number*-1 : $number;
    
       // UPDATE ONE PROD. QUANT. 'ope' -> calcul operation
       $ARR_pdo = array( 'id' => (int) $id,
                            'ope' => $number );
       $sql = 'UPDATE products SET
          quant = IF(quant+:ope >= 0, quant+:ope, 0) WHERE id=:id';
    
       // prepa. SQL
       $request = $DATA_BASE->prepare($sql);
    
       // exec. request
       $request->execute($ARR_pdo);
    
       // PDO closeCursor
       $request->closeCursor();
    
       // return true for test
       return true;
   }
   /**
    * Set_quantity_product::update_quant_prod( $id, $number, $to_do );
    */
    
 }
 /**
  * Class Set_quantity_product
  */

?>
```

Use : ( consider you have a product with an id=42 )

```
Set_quantity_product::update_quant_prod( 42, 5, 'decr' );
```

if your quant in DB is 6 -> this set the value at 1

if your quant in DB is 5 -> this set the value at 0

if your quant in DB is 4 -> this set the value at 0