# MySQL to PHP Integer Math

Tags: php

I have a MySQL table with an integer column in it called `count` which I'm trying to do some basic math on and then update the value. Here is an example of one such task I'm trying to do.

```
$sql = 'SELECT count FROM triggers WHERE id = ?';
$params = array($id);
$result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql, $params);

$row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);

$count = intval($row[0]);
if ($count = 0)
   return -1;
$newCount = $count - 1;

$sql = 'UPDATE triggers SET count = ? WHERE id = ?';
$params = array($newCount, $id);
$result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $sql, $params);
```

The problem I'm having is that `$newCount` always equals -1, so the database value of `count` is updated to -1. In one particular example run, `$count` was equal to 84, so it passed the if statement. But then instead of `$newCount` being set to 83, it gets set to -1.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the MySQL value being treated as a string instead of an integer, but I thought `intval()` would solve that. I also tried using `(int)` instead, but no difference.

Comment: `echo $count` before if statement and check its value

Comment: It's possible that count is a reserved word, and needs backticks in your query (this making it fail and be "false" which is casted to 0, then 1 is subtracted from it). Also, I'd recommend you attempt to update the value directly in the query. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277339/decrement-value-in-mysql-but-not-negative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is `if ($count = 0)`. In PHP, `=` is the assignment operator and `==` is the equality comparison operator.

tl;dr: You meant `if ($count == 0)`.

*(Or `if $count === 0`. Although since `$count` is guaranteed to be an integer here, it won't really matter in this case. Using `===`, and only explicitly using `==` where you intend to invoke type fiddling may also be a good habit to get into.)*

Explanation: Let's step through your code. What's happening here is:

1. `$count = intval($row[0]);` sets `$count` to whatever value from the database.
2. `if ($count = 0)` assigns the value of `0` to `$count`, regardless of anything else. It then tests this value of `0` which is *falsey*, causing the if statement block to be skipped and `return -1` is never executed. This is the same as would happen if you directly wrote `if (0)`.
3. `$newCount` is assigned a value of `$count - 1`, or `-1` in all cases since `$count` will always be 0.
4. The query is then executed, `UPDATE`ing the row with, none other than our friend `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if ($count = 0)
```

should read

```
if ($count === 0)
```

This is because you are assigning the value rather than using a comparison operator.
Here is some useful reading regarding operators in php http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp
Hope that helps!

Comment: Just to note the difference between the two operators suggested in the above answers, == will return true after type juggling (string, int, double, bool etc.. values) while === will return true only if they are of the same type (in this case integer).

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is well defined by Ic in your answer list.

I think your code is little bit longer one, It can be done with shorter form with in one query instead of imposing two queries- first select and get count value and update it, you can achieve this by single query like below-

```
UPDATE  triggers
    // if is like ternary operator condition, true value , false value 
    SET count = IF(count > 0, count - 1, count)
WHERE   id = ?
```